# How does ..master work after a fetch

Tags: git

I am reading https://jwiegley.github.io/git-from-the-bottom-up/1-Repository/6-a-commit-by-any-other-name.html and the bit that says

> ..master — This, too, is especially useful after you’ve done a fetch and you want to see what changes have occurred since your last rebase or merge.

is a bit confusing.

What happens when I run `git fetch` so that running for example `git log ..master` will show me the changes that occurred since last rebase or merge?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After the fetch, you will be able to see is your local repositories is out of date. Out of date means someone else push on the remote since the last time you did the fetch.

**Example**

You made a commit since the last fetch (update). Your working tree is like that

`A---B (origin/master) --- C (master)`

If someone else push a D commit, the fetch give you this

`A---B --- C (master)
     \ ---D (origin/master)`

`git log ..master` is equal to `git log HEAD..master`. The command should show you the C commit. If you want to see changes between your local repository and the remote, use the command `git log ..origin/master`.

You can see that you need to merge or rebase your `C` commit before to be able to push.

Comment: Then shouldn't it be git log HEAD..origin/master?  master is my local branch which points to the same commit as HEAD, so I would expect git log HEAD..master to show nothing.

Comment: Yes, it would/should be `HEAD..origin/master`.  But see `git help gitrevisions`: `..origin/master` *means* `HEAD..origin/master`.  If you leave out either side of the `..`, Git fills it in with `HEAD`.  Incidentally, as long as `master` has `origin/master` set as its upstream, the syntax `..@{u}` works.  I have aliases in my `~/.gitconfig` file to use `..@{u}` to see what is incoming.